# How do I pass arrays through a function resulting in storing local arrays into a global array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, global

I have a function, that passes 2 arrays and then produces a further 2 arrays. I am trying to repeat this multiple times taking the following two values of the input array, so say the input arrays 10 values, the function would repeat 5 times.

I have created a function that works, but doesn't loop through a longer array. The input arrays are `X=[0,1]` and `Y[0,2]` just to make sure the code works, ideally these arrays would be longer and the function would chose the next two values in each array every loop.

```
import pandas as pd
from cmath import cos
from xml.etree.ElementTree import PI
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
import csv

import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Geas_csv.csv")

#array1=list(df["x"].values) 
#array2=list(df["y"].values) 

radius = .1
X = []
Y = []
X_10 = []
X = [0,1]
Y = [0,2]

def generate_shape(X,Y):
    gradient=(Y[1]-Y[0])/(X[1]-X[0])
    print (gradient)
    normal=-(1/gradient)
    print (normal)

    new_x_coord = [0,0,0,0,0]
    new_y_coord = [0,0,0,0,0]

    print (math.atan(normal))

    print (radius*math.cos(math.atan(normal)))
    print (radius*math.sin(math.atan(normal)))


    new_x_coord[0] = X[0]+radius*math.cos(math.atan(normal))
    new_x_coord[1] = X[0]-radius*math.cos(math.atan(normal))
    new_x_coord[2] = X[1]-radius*math.cos(math.atan(normal))
    new_x_coord[3] = X[1]+radius*math.cos(math.atan(normal))
    new_x_coord[4] = new_x_coord[0]
    print (new_x_coord)

    new_y_coord[0] = Y[0]+radius*math.sin(math.atan(normal))
    new_y_coord[1] = Y[0]-radius*math.sin(math.atan(normal))
    new_y_coord[2] = Y[1]-radius*math.sin(math.atan(normal))
    new_y_coord[3] = Y[1]+radius*math.sin(math.atan(normal))
    new_y_coord[4] = new_y_coord[0]
    print (new_y_coord)
    plt.plot(new_x_coord, new_y_coord)
    plt.plot(X,Y)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
    return (new_x_coord, new_y_coord)


generate_shape(X,Y)
```

Comment: Create a for-loop, iterate over the array (actually list) indices and feed slices of the lists into `generate_shape`.

Comment: look at grouper in itertools recipes https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#recipes (which you can pip install as more-itertools)